# Simple Joomla Component - link to single item in the menu manager

Tags: php, joomla

I have created a very simple Joomla component that creates a contact us form and lets the users customize which fields are published and mandatory. I used http://www.component-creator.com/ to help me create the base files.

Everything is working so far, a user can create a new form, choose which fields are published and mandatory and then the custom form will show up in the front end.

One problem I have is linking directly to each of the different contact forms the users have created. I go into menu manager, create a new link, choose the component I created, and I have 3 options, show a list of all forms created, show a form on the front end where users can create forms, and the important one: show a single contact form.

When I select show a single contact form, it closes the modal window and creates a link to the contact form, but it does not give me the option to choose which contact form I want to link to. I want it to be like the "Contacts" component, where you can choose to link to a single contact, and then it gives you the option of choosing which contact you want to link to.

Does anybody know where I would start at looking to recreate this?

Thanks

Edit: I found this piece of code in the stand contact module, does this relate to the selecting of the items in the menu manager? I have tried to adjust it for my own component but it doesn't seem to work so far.

```
<?php if ($this->params->get('show_contact_list') && count($this->contacts) > 1) : ?>
    <form action="#" method="get" name="selectForm" id="selectForm">
        <?php echo JText::_('COM_CONTACT_SELECT_CONTACT'); ?>
        <?php echo JHtml::_('select.genericlist', $this->contacts, 'id', 'class="inputbox" onchange="document.location.href = this.value"', 'link', 'name', $this->contact->link);?>
    </form>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: Do you have a field for this in the xml? It should be in the request  fieldset. You probably need to create the JFormField for the data also.

Comment: Is this what I'm looking for? I took it from the standard contact component. I'm not to sure how to create a JFormField, can you point me in the right direction please?  <!-- Add fields to the request variables for the layout. -->
 <fields name="request">
  <fieldset name="request"
   addfieldpath="/administrator/components/com_contact/models/fields"
  >
   <field name="id"
    type="modal_contact"
    description="COM_CONTACT_SELECT_CONTACT_DESC"
    label="COM_CONTACT_SELECT_CONTACT_LABEL"
    required="true"
    edit="true"
    clear="false"
   />
  </fieldset>
 </fields>

Comment: Correct. That will set up the query to look for a record with that id number.